# HTTP 403 during request for URL info in Graph API

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a wordpress blog. I need to index how many times each page was shared and sort my posts by number of shares.

I made small script what makes requests for each page in a blog, like

```
 while ($posts->have_posts()) {
                    $posts->the_post();
                    $obj_fb = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/?id=' . get_permalink()));
                    $likes_fb = $obj_fb->shares;
                    update_post_meta($post->ID, 'meta_fb_likes', $likes_fb, false);
                }
```

Notice I not use any access tokens.

The script works for certain number of pages, like 50 or 100, but when I process large amount of pages, like 300 or so, it takes about a minute and returns an execution error 403 from graph api.

Please advice what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403)

Comment: If you are running this blog on your own domain, then you should rather set it up for domain insights. https://www.facebook.com/insights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using any Access Tokens, and that is exactly the problem. You MUST use an Access Token for that call now. Just use an App Access Token, that´s the easiest one and you don´t need to authorize for that.

How to get all the Access Tokens is explained in the docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Edit: Oh, i see that it still does work for you, but the problem is the API Rate Limit. Well, the only thing you can do to avoid that is to do less calls. There is no specific Limit, but in general "600 calls in 600 seconds" is a good rule you will find in many threads.

Comment: I sent this request without a token and everything was ok, but it was a single request. Is there a frequency limitation or limitation for usages of API methods without tokens?

Comment: as you can read in my answer, there are no specific limits. but API calls with a token are less likely to get limited afaik.

Comment: but your main problem is that you are doing too many calls. an access token will not really help you there, you need to reduce the amount.